# Delphi - how to create folder by Indy on my HTTP page

Tags: http, delphi, firemonkey, indy10, idhttp

Can anybody help me with folder creation on my HTTP server (It is SanDisk Connect WiFi)

SanDisk has a own address :  http://172.25.63.1/myconnect/

I am able by Indy from Android to do follow :

- download files from ->> IdHTTP1.Get
- upload separated files to ->> IdHTTP1.Put
- delete files on HTTP ->>
  IdHttp1.Delete('http://172.25.63.1/myconnect/XYZ.pdf',TStringStream.Create(''));

But I can not find methode, how to create DIRECTORY (FOLDER) .

Can anybody has a better experiences as I  ?

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: The HTTP protocol has no commands for creating folders. You will likely need to `POST` to a server-side script that then creates the folder.

Comment: You may want to try MKCOL.

Comment: Thanks for the tips to all. Please , do U have any example with POST? Or any example with MKCOL ?  Really thaks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Creation of a folder at HTTP server side requires that the server support the [WEBDAV protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) which is an extension of the HTTP protocol.

At client side, Indy in your case, you have to send the [MKCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) command to the HTTP server. Indy has a `TIdWebDAV` component, which has a `DAVMakeCollection()` method for sending a `MKCOL` command.

Note: WebDav is described in this [specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) but not all servers implement it.